# How error interface is exposed outside when starts with small letter

Tags: go, interface

In the Go language specification its said things which needs to be exported outside package must starts with capital letter. I am wondering how `error` interface is exposed outside and can be accessible anywhere even though it starts with small letter  unlike other interfaces starts with capital letter like `Stringer`.

Comment: Its like asking how int can be exposed if not written as Int or why you can access len. That stuf is _built_ _into_ the language itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) is a builtin type just like `int`, `bool`, `string` etc. I guess you've never wondered why `int` is available despite starting with a lowecased letter.

Builtin types are [predeclared identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), they are implicitly declared in the [universe block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) and so available everywhere without any imports or qualifiers.

Answer (score 4):

`error` is a special case, defined [in the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors):

> The predeclared type error is defined as
>
> ```
> type error interface {
>     Error() string
> }
> ```
>
> It is the conventional interface for representing an error condition, with the nil value representing no error. For instance, a function to read data from a file might be defined:
>
> ```
> func Read(f *File, b []byte) (n int, err error)
> ```

As historical trivia, in a pre-release version of Go, it was part of a standard library package, but this lead to a dependency nightmare, so they made it a special case.